# Printing Unicode characters in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I am using python version 3.8.5.

I have a following row in excel file:

```
SystemId    URL             FIELD           VALUE
794         google.com/sear Organic_Price   Fâ€¯CFAÂ 20
```

having `VALUE` as `Fâ€¯CFAÂ 20`

Which is giving me this error: `could not convert string to float: 'f\u202fcfa20'`

when I try to `df_price_all['VALUE'] = df_price_all['VALUE'].astype(float)`

I tried to print this value in python terminal but I get
[image]

Why are the other weird characters not getting printed?

Also by default the Unicode encoding scheme is assumed to be `utf-8` but can we verify this in python3?

Comment: I don't think MS Excel is using `utf-8` encoding but rather `cp1252`. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15502713/42346

Comment: Why are you expecting `float(randomtext)` to not fail anyway?

Comment: There is no default encoding scheme. Python usually use operating system deafult, which it is often UTF-8 is most common operating systems but on Windows. If you know the encoding, you should force such encoding on reading (so you will not have surprises on other computers).

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: how did you create this excel file? Maybe you should rather fix code which creates this file.

Comment: if you want to get value `20` then `split(" ")` text and get only last element

Comment: The file is encoded in UTF-8, but Excel is using a legacy (ANSI) encoding, probably Windows-1252.  Write the file with UTF-8 w/ BOM instead (`encoding='utf-8-sig'` in Python) and Excel will read it properly.  Excel expects the BOM signature to use UTF-8.