# Python to loop through .py scripts for key-word

Tags: python

A file directory (Windows 10) that used to store many "*.py" scripts.

I want to loop through the .py scripts to find out, which of them contains the specific key-word.

What would be the better way than below, because it often encounters error as:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position xxxx: invalid continuation byte

(I've also tried to use 'latin-1' encoding, or read the scripts in 'rb' way)

```
import os, re

# Define the directory to search in and the keyword to look for
directory = '/path_to_directory'
keyword = 'the_keyword'

# Regular expression pattern to match the keyword
pattern = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(keyword)))

# Function to search for the keyword in a file
def search_in_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
            if pattern.search(line):
                print(f'Found keyword "{keyword}" in {file_path} at line {line_number}:')
                print(line.strip())

# Loop through the directory and its subdirectories
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            search_in_file(file_path)
```

Comment: are you on a linux or mac? you could easily use `ack` or `grep` for this. or python's `ast` module could also work if you know the keyword corresponds to a specific object. also, make sure you're using the [correct encoding for your environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). include an example script that throws the error for a more specific answer

Comment: @willwrighteng, thanks for the comment. sorry forgot to mentioned, it's in Windows.

Comment: since you're treating the python scripts as txt files you'll have to use the [correct encoding for windows systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502619/correctly-reading-text-from-windows-1252cp1252-file-in-python). also, [bash is now available on windows](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/)

Comment: If you are actually search for keyword, you need to parse the file and walk through the AST tree. Otherwise, you will get results also from comments and strings.

Comment: I agree with @jurez. navigating python scripts with the ast module is a platform agnostic method

Answer (score 1):

- You can handle the exception with try/except.

Sample Code:

```py
# Function to search for the keyword in a file
def search_in_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            # rest of the code 
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print(f'Error decoding file: {file_path}')
```

- You are getting this error maybe cause some of the python files contain non-UTF-8 encoded characters.

Comment: thank you. In a case when the key-word exists in a script that has the UnicodeDecodeError, would the search result be ignored?

Comment: If the error occurs it will print the error and continue to the next part of your code

Answer (score 0):

Tried the way to get to know the encoding of the .py file, and apply it, before search the key-word, and found it works.

```
import os, re, glob
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

# Define the directory to search in and the keyword to look for
directory = '/path_to_directory'
keyword = 'the_keyword'

# Regular expression pattern to match the keyword
pattern = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(keyword)))

# Function to search for the keyword in a file
def search_in_file(file_path, give_me):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding=give_me) as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
            if pattern.search(line):
                print(f'Found keyword "{keyword}" in {file_path} at line {line_number}:')
                print(line.strip())

# Loop through the directory and its subdirectories
files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.py")

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'rb') as ff:            # get to know the encoding of the .py file
       content = ff.read()               # get to know the encoding of the .py file
    suggestion = UnicodeDammit(content)  # get to know the encoding of the .py file

    search_in_file(f, suggestion.original_encoding)
```